# How to do game limits? Windows Forms Application C#

Tags: c#, forms

I'm doing a c# game on Windows Forms Application, and I'm trying to do game limits - it's mean that the player can't escape from the form's screen.

I thought to do it like this: (player_Deagle that's my Player)

```
 if (player_Deagle.Right < 0)
        {
            // But I do not know what to put here.
        }
```

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution is to use `Math.Max` or `Math.Min` like

```
const int RightBound = 1000;
//Don't allow the user to leave the right bound
player_Deagle.Right = Math.Min(player_Deagle.Right, RightBound);
```

or

```
const int LeftBound = 0;
//Don't allow the user to leave the left bound
player_Deagle.Right = Math.Max(player_Deagle.Right, LeftBound);
```

This is also working with upper and lower bounds.

If you need to set the player to the other side of the form, you could do it like

```
//Set the player to the left bound if it leaves the right bound
player_Deagle.Right = player_Deagle.Right > RightBound ? LeftBound : player_Deagle.Right;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I want to make a bird flying across the screen, but I want it to stay on the screen and when it get to the limit of the left side of the form it flying back to the right side of the screen - again & again.

Comment: `player_Deagle.Right` is a property that is not allowed to set. Try to find out how to set the positon of your player. Maybe there is a method like `SetPosition` or `SetRight` available? (or simply change `{ get; }` to `{ get; set; }` at the `Right` property)

Comment: Sorry about my annoying. but I did not understand how to do it.

Comment: if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
            {
                player_Deagle.Left -= 10;
            }
 
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
            {
                player_Deagle.Left += 10;
            }

Comment: The complete player class would be helpful - edit your question and paste some code up there :-)

Comment: So, what do you mean my friend? :-) maybe: https://pastebin.com/8CHGpnSs

Comment: No, the the type of the `player_Deagle` instance

Comment: In my game I have a menu, when you can choose a weapon... (Player_Deagle, player_M4A1 & player_AK47) so player_Deagle is the one I'm using now. It is a picturebox that moves by keys (ASWD) so the code that I've sent is about the picturebox movement. I got one more question plesae - How to display messagebox only once? Thank you. :-)